# How to configure Windows 7 for maximum, realistic, every day security?

Tags: windows-7, security

Being realistic I want to be able to do most things: install apps, go online, etc. but want to be safe and prevent any unnecessary problems (i.e. reinstalls!)

From what I've gathered Microsoft Security Essentials would be a good bet?
Also, would you recommend UAC is left as is or to be tweaked to be an optimal gatekeeper?
Anything else I need to consider? (In XP, I currently have an anti-virus app - mainly for emails.)
Are there any gotchas that Microsoft have left in?

Answer (score 4):

- Always have an antivirus and a software firewall installed.

  - ZoneAlarm is an excellent firewall and has a [free version](http://www.zonealarm.com/security/en-us/zonealarm-pc-security-free-firewall.htm)
  - [Avast Home Edition](http://www.avast.com/eng/avast_4_home.html) is a good free antivirus
  - [Comodo Internet Security](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/) is a good firewall and antivirus suite (also free)
- Always use a password for all of your accounts. Choose one that is at least 8 characters long, and contains upper- and lowecase, numeric and punctuation characters.
- Rename the Administrator account
- Use your PC with normal user privileges, run installers, etc. as administrator. Jeff Atwood, one of the founders of this site, has a [great article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000891.html) about this.

Comment: Does Windows 7 need a firewall over and above what it provides?

Comment: Windows 7's firewall now offers outbound protection, so it is certainly better than before but honestly I don't want to experiment with it and just use what has been keeping my computer safe for years.

Answer (score 1):

point your user data to a different partition/drive, create a disk image of your system drive. this is your best insurance against tedious 'reinstalls'. this way you can restore your system to a clean state in no time.

anything else can be filed under the 'principle of hope'.

Answer (score 0):

- Windows 7 is built upon the security foundations of the Windows Vista® operating system while improving auditing and the User Account Control (UAC) experience.
- Windows 7 helps IT control what software can run in their environment with AppLocker™.
- Windows 7 enhances the core features of BitLocker™ Drive Encryption with the introduction of BitLocker To Go™ for removable storage devices.

Take a look at page about [Windows 7 Security Enhancements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560691.aspx)